# add text over image in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, web, fpdf

is there a way to add text with certain parameters over images in pdf?

can this text be for example

$pdf->Cell(0,260,''.$person["CA"],'C',0 ,1);

this: .$person["CA"] i called from a global in the top of the php file.. but would like to know if its possible too. ..??

any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such built-in function in FPDF, but that doesn't mean you can't write your own routine to automate the process. Libraries like FPDF are designed to provide base functionality for you to extend.